# How to access images directly from Google Cloud Storage (GCS) when using Keras?

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I have developed a model in Keras that works perfectly when reading data stored locally.  However, I now want to take advantage of Google Cloud Platform's GPUs for training the model.  I have set up the GPU on GCP and am working in a Jupyter notebook.  I have moved my images to Google Cloud Storage.

My question is:

**How can I access these images (specifically the directories -  training, validation, test) directly from Cloud Storage using the Keras' flow_from_directory method of the [ImageDataGenerator](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) class?**

here's my directory structure in Google Cloud Storage (GCS):

```
mybucketname/
      class_1/
          img001.jpg
          img002.jpg
          ...
      class_2/
          img001.jpg
          img002.jpg
          ...
      class_3/
          img001.jpg 
          img002.jpg
          ...
```

Comment: I've found that copying the files directly from Cloud Storage to the VM works via `import os, sys os.system('gsutil cp -r gs://mybucketname/ .')` but that's not the elegant solution I was hoping for…

Comment: Have you found a better solution? I am currently searching for one and I have only found some workarounds.